# How to detect in runtime that app uses swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm developing framework(objc) and I need to detect that application uses swift. It doesn't matter that app developed on swift completely or it's swift/objc hybrid.

Do you have and ideas how to get this information? I've thought about objc runtime but I don't know how I can implement that.

Great thanks.

I don't know why my previous question has been closed. But I'll try to be more focused: I need to get information how many clients which integrate my framework use swift as a programming language so I must to detect that a project uses swift.

Comment: First, no, it's highly unlikely you could detect that Swift was used. iOS apps are compiled... not interpreted. Second, even if you *could*, how would you be getting that information? Are you planning on putting some type of functionality in your framework that (secretly) sends data to your server when a user runs an app?

Comment: @DonMag maybe his stuff in fact is a reporting framework or has one as a dependency. Sending the described data shouldn't be that hard together with that all the other data-points that make marketing people happy.

Comment: @DonMag I just want to collect a statistics

Comment: @Till exactly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find below the possible approach based on public documented `dyld` API available since iPhone2 and valid for all modern iOS versions. And `libswiftCore.dylib` is present always for swift.

Taking into account that Swift might be in some application plug-ins, the below function should be called regularly (or at least till first positive result) on your framework API call.

```
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>

BOOL isSwiftLoaded() {
    return NSVersionOfRunTimeLibrary("libswiftCore.dylib") != -1; 
            // -1 is documented indicator that library is not loaded
}
```

Comment: That's great solution! Many thanks! Can you say where did you find the solution? I've read apple's documentation and a lot of other articles but I've never seen before your really great solution.

Comment: Just experience... and all good habit, from C background, to read API headers/interfaces, even before documentation. ))